# wcf rest send dictionary as parameter

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a rest Service like

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     UriTemplate = "Dispatche")]
     string Dispatche(Dictionary<string, DispatchParameter> dispatchParameters);
```

and my DispatchParameter code is like

```
public class DispatchParameter
{

    public string ServiceName { get; set; }

    public string ServiceUrl { get; set; }

    public string Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

In client when I call my service the service parameter(dispatchParameters) dose not value

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var param = new Dictionary<string, DispatchParameter>();
param.Add("Persons",new DispatchParameter(){ServiceName = "PersonService",ServiceUrl = "PersonService URL"});
var result = client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:1822/DispatcherService.svc/Dispatche", dispatchParameters).Result;
```

Is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: can you try converting `param` to `json` brfore sending?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh the PostAsJsonAsync method do this

Comment: try removing `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest`.also , do we need `[DataContract]` attribute here?I don't think so, I had problems retrieving `json` when using this attribute

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I remove BodyStyle and [DataContract] .but my problem not solved

Comment: did you find a solution? try `HttpRequest`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh no.HttpRequest?